# Local Notifications showing more than once

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

First of all, sorry for my english.
I've got a problem with an app that creates multiple local notifications. I'm scheduling them in a for loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
    compteur++;

    UILocalNotification *prototypeNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    prototypeNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    prototypeNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    prototypeNotification.alertBody = @"ALERTE PILULE !!!!!";
    prototypeNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
    [prototypeNotification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
    prototypeNotification.fireDate = itemDate;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:prototypeNotification];
    [prototypeNotification release];

    itemDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:itemDate options:0];


    if (compteur == 21) {
        compteur = 0;
        itemDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comps2 toDate:itemDate options:0];

    }
}
```

When the firedate has come, it works well but it shows not only one but 2 or 3 or 6 alerts sometimes... And I just can't find why... Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; 
    //here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    UIApplication *APP =[UIApplication sharedApplication];
     NSArray *oldnotification = [APP scheduledLocalNotifications];
    if (oldnotification>=0)
    {
         [APP cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
}
```

Are you adding this code in above module.. to cancel old notifications??

Comment: hmm .. question or answer?

Comment: @kleopatra  that's Question with Answer :P                               if you are not adding this method..then this is Answer and if you are adding this then it's not :P